# Rails 3: Couldn't find User without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I'm currently working on my first rails project (a photo uploading site), and am getting an error on a form that creates a new photo album that belongs to a user. I'm trying to use the Paperclip gem. It's giving me the error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in AlbumsController#create

Couldn't find User without an ID
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with the instance variables in my create action, but I don't see what's wrong. Any guidance would be helpful. Here are my files:

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for (@album), :remote => true, :html => { :id => "uploadform", :multipart => true } do |f| %>
<div>
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>


    <%= f.label :description %>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>


    <%= f.fields_for :avatar do |avatar_form| %>
    <%= avatar_form.label :avatar, "Upload" %>
    <%= avatar_form.file_field :avatar, :multiple => true %>
    <% end %>


    <%=f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

albums_controller create action:

```
def create
  @users = User.all
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @album = @user.albums.build(params[:album])
  if @album.save
    flash[:success] = "Album created!"
  end 
end
```

config/routes

```
Pholder::Application.routes.draw do
resources :users do
  resources :albums 
end

resources :albums do
  resources :pictures
end
```

Album model

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :avatar, :name, :description
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users

  has_attached_file :avatar
end
```

Let me know if you need to see any other files.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a new album, there is no `user_id` in the albums hash as I first thought. I added a new method that merges in the user id to the hash.

```
def create
  @users = User.all
  @album = Album.new(params[:album].merge!(:user_id => current_user))
  if @album.save
    flash[:success] = "Album created!"
  end 
end
```

If you would rather not have user_id in `attr_accessible` in your Album model, you can assign it separately.

```
def create
  @users = User.all
  @album = Album.new(params[:album])
  @album.user_id = current_user.id
  if @album.save
    flash[:success] = "Album created!"
  end 
end
```

Comment: ah I jumped to a conclusion too quickly. Since this is a new Album you need to put in the current_user id. Are you using devise? do you have any kind of `current _user` variable?

Comment: hey. i actually haven't gotten to sessions or the current_user variable yet, but I know what they are since I've done tutorials and read a book on rails. this is my first project so i wanted to get the forms all working before i worked with sessions. Would you recommend that I look up devise first? I'm not too sure if I'm working in the right order

Comment: If you haven't dealt with authentication at all yet and aren't grouping entries by the user they belong to, then I would use the 2nd example and comment out the line before the save until you do.

Comment: When you set up some kind of login, you can uncomment the line.